# Reverse String Program

Tags: java, string, reverse

I have written a short String reverse program in C++. I decided to write it in Java, and so I did. However, once I completed writing the program, I encountered several errors that I have tried to fix but cannot fix. One of the errors was an ArrayOutOfBounds exception. Please help me fix the errors. The C++ program worked fine. Below  is the Java code. Please note that I do not want to use inbuilt functions.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args){
      Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
      String word;
      int i = 0;
      boolean inp = true;
      System.out.println("Enter one or more words to be reversed:");
      word = scan.nextLine();
      char wordArray[] = word.toCharArray();
      while(wordArray[i]!='\0')
          i++;
      while(inp == true){
          i--;
          System.out.println(wordArray[i]);
          if(i==0){
              System.out.println();
              break;
          }
        }
     }
  }
```

Comment: You may use length() method to find the length of your string.

Comment: BTW, reversing isn't as easy as it sounds if you care about the integrity of your string.  There are "combining characters" which meld with the character next to them, and blindly reversing the string changes which char comes after and before.  See http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2009/11/02/omg-ponies-aka-humanity-epic-fail.aspx (and search for "Les Miserables") to see an example of what i'm talking about.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no null-terminating character in Java strings; they have a `length()` method you should use to determine length.

Also, the `while` loop would be more idiomatic as:

```
while (true) {
    ...
}
```

Or as a simple `for` loop.

Comment: But I converted the String to a character array which does have a null terminating character, so shouldn't I be able to use the first while loop?

Comment: why would the array have a null-character if the string didn't ?

Comment: @dvader123: The char array doesn't contain the nul either.  It contains exactly the same chars as the String did -- no more, no less.  Java isn't C; arrays know their length here, so you don't need a terminating character to know how long the string is.

Comment: @dvader123 Arrays have a length property, `wordArray.length` (don't ask why it's a property :( that you can also use. Btw, it's not an array of words, it's an array of characters; IMO `chars` or `wordChars` would be more communicative.

Comment: Oh okay, so I use the length() function to go to the end of the String in the first while loop. Right?

Comment: @dvader123 What do you mean by "go to the end"? length() method just gives you the character count from the String.

Comment: @dvader123: You don't need the first while loop at all.  You can replace it with `i = wordArray.length;`.

Answer (score 3):

This is another possibility, perhaps simpler:

```
public String reverse(String str) {
    char[] chars = str.toCharArray();
    int n = chars.length;
    for (int i = 0; i < n/2; i++) {
        char tmp = chars[i];
        chars[i] = chars[n-i-1];
        chars[n-i-1] = tmp;
    }
    return new String(chars);
}
```

And although you mentioned that you don't want to use built-in functions, the most idiomatic way would be this:

```
public String reverse(String str) {
    return new StringBuilder(str).reverse().toString();
}
```

Comment: Shorter; not simpler. The naive solution is simpler. But +1 for alternative implementation.

Answer (score 0):

strings in java are not necessarily null terminated, you should use String.length() method to find out how long it is.

Answer (score 0):

Java Strings are not zero-terminated, thus the byte array created from string isn't either. You used a loop to determine the length of your array, but that loop doesn't find a byte with value 0, so it goes over the range. Use `word.length()` instead.

The second thing: You used `System.out.println` to print the character - that inserts a linebreak after each character. Is this intended?